# is Number Divisible by another in Swift

Tags: swift

here is code but somehow its not working

```
func isDivisible(x: Int, y: Int) -> Bool {
    if x % y == 0 {
    return true 
    } else { return false }
 }
print(isDivisible(10, y: 2))
```

Error:  **error: extraneous argument label 'y:' in call
print(isDivisible(10, y: 2))**

Comment: Try removing the `y:` part (`isDivisible(10, 2)`). Also, you should edit the question title. The problem isn't the divisibility check but the syntax.

Comment: Compile fine on my Xcode 7.1.1. What version are you using?

Comment: its working fine on 7.0.1 too

Comment: xcode 6.4, maybe it is bug

Comment: I don't know, but sometimes, when you upgrade the xcode you get a new swift version. And a new swift version changes a lot of things

Comment: The handling of (external) parameter names changed between Xcode 6.4 (Swift 1.2) and Xcode 7 (Swift 2). I am sure that this is documented in the Release notes. The above code compiles with Xcode 7 but not with Xcode 6.4.

Comment: above syntax is working fine in both swift 1.2 (xcode 6.4) and swift 2.0 (xcode 7.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mixing different variants handling of external parameter names. In Swift 1.2 *no* labels should be there, in Swift 2 either combination works, and in Swift 3 *both* labels have to be there.